# Updating controller reference variable for access via Javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a controller which creates a record (and consequently an ID).  After the record is created, variables are set.  However, when I attempt to access the variable after the controller action has run, it's not getting the updated values.

After I run the {!save} method the record is created BUT the controller reference variable is not updated.  How can I get at that new ID value?

**Javascript/VF**

```
<apex:commandButton value="navigate to record" onclick="navigateToActivity(); return false;"/>    

<script>
   function navigateToActivity() 
   {
     var controllerValues = '{!recordID} {!geoLat}'
     alert(controllerValues);
   }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    public Activity__C act {get; set;}
    public User owner {get; set;}
    public boolean hasLocation {get; set;} 
    public double geoLat {get; set;}
    public double geoLong {get; set;}
    public string recordID {get; set;}

    public QuickCreateActivityController(){
       act = new Activity__c();
       owner = new user();   
       hasLocation = false;
       geoLat = 0.0;
       geoLong = 0.0;
       recordId = string.valueof(act.id);
    }

    public void save() {  

        system.debug(hasLocation);
        system.debug(string.valueof(geoLat));
        system.debug(string.valueof(geoLong));
        system.debug('pre insert id' + recordId);
        /**************ID is blank********/

        checkForWorkday();             
        insert act;
        recordID = string.valueof(act.Id);
        system.debug('post insert id' + recordId);
        /**************ID is Created********/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to rerender this section

```
<apex:commandButton value="navigate to record" onclick="navigateToActivity(); return false;" rerender="panel" />    
<apex:outputpanel id="panel" >
<script>
   function navigateToActivity() 
   {
     var controllerValues = '{!recordID} {!geoLat}'
     alert(controllerValues);
   }
</script>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

then you will get updated value.

Comment: It's still coming up Null

<apex:commandButton value="navigate to record" onclick="navigateToActivity(); return false;"  rerender="jsPanel" />

Comment: <apex:outputPanel id="jsPanel">
<script>
 function navigateToActivity() 
    {
        var controllerValues = '{!recordID} {!geoLat}'
        alert(controllerValues);</script>
</apex:outputPanel>

Comment: @tjcinnamon where you are calling controller method here?

Comment: yes, I created a secondary button for testing to make sure the write op finished:  

 <button id="btnSave" onclick="prepToSavePosition(); return false;" >Log my location</button>

Comment: prepToSavePosition() calls an action function which calls {!save} and creates the record.  The log for the controller shows the value is updated.

Comment: @tjcinnamon then rerender this section from that action. And then check.

Comment: Now it doesn't work without the button.  Curious if I can re-render during the call stack.  Will post a new question

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129408/call-rerender-in-middle-of-call-stack-to-navigate-to-new-record-on-create