# Call rerender in middle of call-stack to navigate to new record on create

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

So I have a controller which creates a record and an ID is set on create.  I have a controller reference that works after the stack is complete but not in the middle:

**example that works:**
1) button calls controller function via action function

2) controller function creates record

3) action function re-renders Javascript to reflect the new values

4) everything completes and I create a second button to click which is allowed to use the rerendered reference

```
  <button id="btnSave" onclick="prepToSavePosition();return false;">Log my location</button>

<apex:commandbutton id="runAfterControllerMethod" onclick="navigateToActivity();">
```

**Example that doesn't work**

1) button calls controller function via action function: *same*

2) controller function creates record: *same*

3) action function re-renders Javascript to reflect the new values: *same*

4) from the javascript method that's running OR the button that initiated the call a function is run that uses those references

```
<button id="btnSave" onclick="prepToSavePosition(); navigateToActivity(); return false;">Log my location</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the syntax

```
<button id="btnSave" onclick="prepToSavePosition(); navigateToActivity(); return false;">Log my location</button>
```

when you click the button first onclick call the `actionfunction` which starts its processing but before actionfunction complete its processing. Second method get called thats why you are not able to get update value.

call this method from oncomplete attribute of your `actionfuncion` and it will solve your problem.